# jquery change previous content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, event-handling

When i change a province in my select list, a new list gets updated with new checkboxes.
Now when the change occurs i want .change() added to those new checkboxes (its for when parent gets selected, chillds should be selected). But when i log the object, i see i got the items from the previous list and not from the current.

Its seems like the change function still works with the previous values in the list, but not with the new updated ones. I can't figure out how to get the current items from the list. Someone an idea?

```
$('.select-province').change(function() {

        //I log the previous list, but need the current updated one
        var test = $(this).parent().contents();
        console.log(test);

            //Not really important for understanding the problem
        $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
            //alert('test');
            console.log($(this));
            $(this).parent().siblings('ul')
                .find("input[type='checkbox']")
                .prop('checked', this.checked);
        });

});
```

Comment: Why are you nesting onchange event inside an other onchange event? You should maybe provide a jsFiddle

Comment: When 1 list changes, another list changes. And the list that get's changed is a hiararchy of checkboxes. So when the parent gets checked, the childs should be checked ass well. So when the event on the parent checkbox occurs, the child checkboxes need to be checked.

Comment: Well, a jsFiddle would make your issue really easier to understand

Comment: I'll make a clear one this evening. Change on select list triggers ajax call. The delay of the alex callback wich changes the content is probably slower then the jquery function.

Comment: Sounds like you should delegate event then, as in asnwer posted below

Answer (score 2):

**Try:**

```
.live('change',function() {
```

**This if you are using jQuery  above version 1.7** :

```
$(document).on('change','.select-province', function() {
```